# trim() cuts too much when second argument is used

Tags: php

```
$string1 = "uploads/projects";
$string2 = "uploads/";

echo trim($string1, $string2); // outputs "rojects"
```

Can anyone tell me why `trim()` function is outputting `rojects` and not `projects` string?

Comment: Because trim takes as second parameter a string that is seen as a list of characters.

Comment: write so `str_replace($string2, '', $string1);`

Comment: @splash58 It shouldn't be used like that, because `$string2` may occur not only on the beggining of `$string1`. I want to change string only on the beggining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the php manual of [`trim`](http://php.net/trim):

> Optionally, the stripped characters can also be specified using the
>   character_mask parameter. Simply list **all characters** that you want
>   to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

The second parameter behaves as a set of characters and not as a whole string.

So the character `p` which appears in your mask parameter `uploads` is being removed from the `uploads/projects` string.

Maybe you should use `str_replace` instead.